# How can I suppress popup errors in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am working with an IBM product called Presto. It converts green screens to browser based pages. To do this it does strange things. I am dealing with text fields that randomly popup in different places. I am using the following code for each object to overcome:

```
document.getElementById("C0816").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("C0816").style.left = "190px";
document.getElementById("C0816").style.top = "216px";
```

This has worked well until now. I am dealing with a page that will remove objects (text fields) & replace with different objects. This causes an error when it can't find the missing Id.
How can I suppress this error? I have tried several examples on this board but I am new to JavaScript & I am obviously placing it in the code wrong. Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: The ids are always different each time you see a popup?

Comment: You may want to look into classes or elements vs the IDs, though that will depend upon the HTML it outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the element exists before accessing properties.

```
const elem = document.getElementById("C0816");
if(elem) {
  elem.style.position = 'absolute';
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You are awesome!
Because there were more that 1 element I had to increment the constant:
'code'
const elem1 = document.getElementById("C0616");
if(elem1) {
 document.getElementById("C0616").style.position = "absolute";
 document.getElementById("C0616").style.left = "190px";
 document.getElementById("C0616").style.top = "162px";  
}

const elem2 = document.getElementById("C0816");
if(elem2) {
 document.getElementById("C0816").style.position = "absolute";
 document.getElementById("C0816").style.left = "190px";
 document.getElementById("C0816").style.top = "216px"; 
}

Comment: If they are all being assigned the same values you should consider doing this by adding a class instead.